# TableView data not showing after updating Firebase code (Swift 2, Firebase 3.x)

Tags: uitableview, firebase, swift2, xcode7, firebase-realtime-database

Have been updating my project to the newest firebase code and am now running into an issue.

Yesterday my app was working fine w/ the updates I implemented and all of the sudden my tableView is no longer displaying data and it's not even printing the data in my console.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MGSwipeTableCell


class FeedVCViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var posts = [Post]()
static var imageCache = NSCache()
var isPostHidden = false
var likeRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var dislikeRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var postRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var postLiked = false
var postDisliked = false

private var _post: Post?

var post: Post? {
    return _post
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 38, height: 38))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "unilogo2Whtie")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value)

        self.posts = []

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots {

                print("SNAP: \(snap)")

                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key, dictionary: postDict)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return posts.count


}
```

I must have done something wrong in the update I'm assuming, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised you're not getting an error on the following lines:

```
var likeRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var dislikeRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
var postRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
```

For me, I had to add the following line below import Firebase in order not to get an error when declaring the database reference:

```
import FirebaseDatabase
```

Then in your viewDidLoad method you need to add the reference to your database

```
likeRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

However, with this new version of Firebase, you don't need a separate reference for likeRef, dislikeRef and postRef. You can make just one main reference and then access the child of the reference for those details.